# How do I convert a ProductReturnType into a matrix?

Tags: c++, eigen

I am using the C++ linear algebra library eigen. I have tried to multiply 2 matrices:

```
static void do_stuff_with_matrix(Eigen::MatrixXf& mat) {
  return;
}

Eigen::MatrixXf a(3, 4);
Eigen::MatrixXf b(4, 5);

Eigen::MatrixXf c = a * b;
do_stuff_with_matrix(c);
```

Unfortunately, I get a compiler error stating that `ProductReturnType` (which `c` is) cannot be converted into a `Eigen::MatrixXf&`. How do I perform this conversion?

Comment: can you post your '*' operator overloading function? so that it is easy to find error.

Comment: Thanks, what's the `'*' operator overloading function`?

Comment: Eigen::MatrixXf c = a * b; For matrix multiplications you should overload operator ' * ' . I think you have implemented this function. so please upload this function.

Comment: I think the eigen library wrote `operator*()`.

Comment: You need to verify return type of operator *() function.

Comment: According to my understanding of your question. I think we can not multiply 3 by 4 to 4 by 5 matrices.

Comment: @rishikeshtadaka: In that case you might want to read a book on most basic linear algebra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eigen uses lazy evaluation in order to prevent unnecessary temporaries and other things. As a result `c` is essentially a [`ProductReturnType`](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/structEigen_1_1ProductReturnType.html), a optimized structure for a matrix product:

> ```
> template<typename Lhs, typename Rhs, int ProductType>
> class Eigen::ProductReturnType< Lhs, Rhs, ProductType >
> ```
>
> Helper class to get the correct and optimized returned type of `operator*`. [see also [2](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/classEigen_1_1MatrixBase.html#adf2ccabec2f82b36f445e9c7f58c9080)]

In order to create a real matrix from a expression of the form `A * B` you need to evaluate it directly:

```
Eigen::MatrixXf c = (a * b).eval();
do_stuff_with_matrix(c);
```

See [this page](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/TopicLazyEvaluation.html) for more information about Eigen's lazy evaluation and aliasing.